# Is there any open source framework that can provide a update service?

Tags: web-services, web, ejb-3.0

I provide a web service, but sometimes I need to update my web service. When i update the source code, i need to stop the service, then install the new service package.

Here is the problem:

1 I really don't want to stop the service when updating

2 I just need to update some specific features. But now I have to update the whole package. This makes the updating process long and heavy.

I think EJB would be a solution. But i need more advice.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to think on lines of dynamic class loading tools. One of the tools i am aware is JRebel. You might want to have a look at it.
Other opensource alternative is springloaded. But its still naive and under constant development.